# unable to store image in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, datatable

hi i have web application in which i need to store image into one of column of datatble
but i am getting error when doing this.Here is my code i tried for this.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Companyaddress", typeof(System.String));
dt.Columns.Add("CompEmail", typeof(System.String));
dt.Columns.Add("CompTelephone", typeof(System.String));
dt.Columns.Add("logoname", typeof(byte[]));
//dt.Columns.Add("logoname", typeof(System.Byte[]));

for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; rowNumber++)
{
    imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber]["logoname"] = GetByteArray("abc.jpg");
    dt.Rows.Add(imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][0].ToString(), 
                imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][1].ToString(), 
                imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][2].ToString(), 
                imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][3].ToString());
 }
```

Getting error

> Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store
>    in logoname Column.  Expected type is Byte[].

on this line

```
dt.Rows.Add(imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][0].ToString(), imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][1].ToString(), imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][2].ToString(), imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][3].ToString());
```

This is functon i call to get image

```
private byte[] GetByteArray(String strFileName)
{
    System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(strFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
    // initialise the binary reader from file streamobject
    System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(fs);
    // define the byte array of filelength

    byte[] imgbyte = new byte[fs.Length + 1];
    // read the bytes from the binary reader

    imgbyte = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32((fs.Length)));
    // add the image in bytearray

    br.Close();
    // close the binary reader

    fs.Close();
    // close the file stream
    return imgbyte;
}
```

what to do? need help.

Comment: Is this related to [Storing image in dataset table from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156967/storing-image-in-dataset-table-from-another-table) ?? Why the same question twice in two different titles??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty ,As in this scenario i was gettitng error while inserting record in datatble in other question i got the same error when merging this datatable with datset so i just asked with diffrent title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is the way you are adding the row the DataTable.

You should use:

```
dt.Rows.Add(imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][0].ToString(),
    imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][1].ToString(), 
    imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][2].ToString(), 
    imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][3] as byte[]);
```

Since your Column 3 corresponds to the byte array field, you may cast it to `byte[]` type. Earlier you were using `.ToString` whereas the method was expecting a `byte[]` type argument. Hence the exception.

For clarity, you may re-write your loop using [DataTable.NewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx) as:

```
for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; rowNumber++)
{
    imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber]["logoname"] = GetByteArray("abc.jpg");
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Companyaddress"] = imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][0].ToString();
    dr["CompEmail"] = imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][1].ToString();
    dr["CompTelephone"] = imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][2].ToString();
    dr["logoname"] = imageDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber][3] as byte[];
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: hi habib,Thanks you trick work perfectly but i am getting same error on other code in same flow.actually i am merging this dattable in dataset which is added as source for one of my crystal report
**dsHeader.Tables[0].Merge(dt,true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);**

on this line i am getting same error,The "logoname" field in dsHeader dataset is of **System.Byte[]** type.As your code work on above scenario can u help me for this

Comment: @sharad, I am not really sure, is the schema of dsHeader.Tables[0] is same as dt ?. you may post a new question regarding your new issue

Comment: @Habib: I think you might need to answer this as well [Storing image in dataset table from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156967/storing-image-in-dataset-table-from-another-table) :D